# Is it possible to use a pseudoterminal to redirect PPP’s dataflow to an application?

Tags: linux, terminal, devices, ppp, pty

I want to set PPP in order to use a pseudoterminal slave (/dev/pts/N) instead of a physical serial link, handle its data flow in an application (from /dev/ptmx) and redirect that flow … somewhere appropriate. 
After reading all the documentation I understand that this is doable, however, I’ve found no trace of someone that actually tried. So, can someone at ease with PTS confirm that I’m not missing something?

I could try myself, but it would involve quite a bit of software development to answer the question.
I’m particularly wondering about dataflow issues (I’d use XOn/Xoff) or latency issues…

Long story ...

I’m on an embedded Linux (Call it device#1). This device has an application that communicates with a second device (Call it device#2) through a homemade protocol on serial link. At the moment, Device#1 use PPP and a modem connected to a second serial link for its communication.
The point is that device#2 also has a modem. So, I want to remove the modem from device#1 in order to reduce the cost of our solution and redirect PPP’s dataflow to the other device/modem.

My idea is to use a pseudoterminal pair, modify the application in order to read the flow from the PTM, encapsulate it in the homemade protocol and send it to device#2. Device#2 can be modified in order to handle this flow properly, that’s not the point.

- Device#2 has no Operating System (I can’t reasonably use socat between the two devices).
- tty0tty could be a solution, but I wish to avoid as far as possible the installation of a package,
- SSL/TCP has to be set up in device#1 (Linux) for security reason. This is mandatory.

Comment: When you say device#2 has no OS, what does it have?

Comment: device#2 is an ARM9 board. It's running an Embedded software developped in ANSI C. Almost no library available (not enough memory).

Answer (score 0):

I've used `pppd` to run traffic through SSH connections before, which should be similar to what you're attempting. I did that after having trouble with traditional SSH tunneling, where the creation/teardown of forwarded TCP connections bogged things down a lot. The ssh+pppd combination worked much better, so hopefully that means you wouldn't have much trouble with latency. I can't speak to the Xon/Xoff situation, though.

I included a line in a `/etc/ppp/peers/<linkname>` file that looked something like this:

```
pty "/usr/bin/ssh -t -P -l username servername"
```

You'd obviously want to replace that `ssh` command with your own tool for translating the serial link.

There are also people who have done the same sort of thing with `socat` and `nc`, so I'd expect this to be doable.